# Why is the direction in port mappings from the design to the test-bench and not vice versa?

Tags: testing, vhdl, test-bench

When testing with a testbench in VHDL we map the I/O from the design we are testing to the I/O of the test bench.

For me, it would make sense to give the input of our design some generated values from the testbench and then observe the output from the design and check if it matches what we expect. (Like in unit testing e.g.)

But when defining the architecture of the testbench:

```
architecture behavior of tb is 
  
  signal tb_input : std_logic := '0'; 
  signal tb_output: std_logic := '0';

  -- Component decl. for the Unit under Test (UUT)
  component design_to_test is 
   port (
      input : in std_logic; 
      output: out std_logic);
  end component design_to_test; 

begin 
   -- Here we initiate the UUT
   UUT : design_to_test
      port map ( 
        input => tb_input
        -- this is what I don't understand. Why are we 
           giving the input of our design to the testbench? 
        output => tb_output
        -- this makes sense to me as we have to observe the 
           the output of our design. 
       ); 
       -- main testing 
end behavior;
```

---

So essentially the part I don't understand is how we use the input of the testbench. Why aren't we defining some input and then giving it to the design to evaluate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you need to stimulate the input of your UUT.

Currently your test bench is not complete.

Add some sequence to assign different values to `tb_input`.

And then add some checks that `tb_output` carries the expected values.

---

The `port map` just tells the simulator (or the synthesizer if you are synthesizing) which ports are connected to what signals of the outer level.

So `input => tb_input` does **not** mean that the data flows from `input` to `tb_input`. It says that the port `input` has to be connected to the signal `tb_input`. The data directions are derived from `in` and `out` keywords.

Look at it as the IC socket and the connected nets, which are the signals of the outer level, and the IC plugged into the socket and its pins, which are the ports of your component.

Comment: Thank you that makes more sense. But regarding the "The data directions is derived from in and out keywords." part: ```input => tb_input``` both have the ```in``` type. Why don't they have the type ```in``` and ```out``` then?

Comment: @stht55 `input` is an input because of the `in` keyword. `tb_input` has no direction: it is a _signal_, a wire, a track on a PCB. If you connect it to a port of _mode_ `in` then that port is an input and will be _driven_ by that signal.   If you connect it to a port of _mode_ `out` then that port is an output and will _drive_ that signal.